# Disable javascript function in specific size of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to disable the javascript function in specific size of screen - and enable it in specific size of screen.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moveleft").click(function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.box__image').animate({'left' : "-=330px"});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to `window`'s size change event

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).on('resize', function() {

    if ($(this).width() < 768) {
      $("#moveleft").click(function() {
        $('.box__image').animate({
          'left': "-=330px"
        });
      });
    } else {
      $("#moveleft").off('click')
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Please help me, it only works when im using toggle device toolbar.

Comment: How do you differentiate the sizes of screen depending on mobile or pc,